# OSX Scheduled Task / Script

Tags: macos, cron, scheduled-tasks, scheduler, file-rename

How would I write a scheduled task on OSX to watch for a specific file and then have the scheduler rename it with an id?

Another program current creates a file, but it keeps getting overwritten. I don't have access to the other program's source code.

I'm a total noob in non-web scripting. Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: is that specific file going to a specific location (i.e. a certain folder?)

Comment: @michael, it is a file going to a specific folder. Its contents are variable.

Answer (score 1):

Check out Folder Actions and Automator. Together they can be pretty powerful. There are lots of blogs out there describing their use.

Comment: Will check out when I get home.